# Cannot encode object in pymongo

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I have this query in mongodb:

```
db.getCollection('users').find(
                            {"first_name": {$in: ['Alex', 'Andrew']}},
                            {'id': 1, '_id': 0}
                            )
```

And have results from this query.
But when I try to run this query in python with pymongo:

```
select_users_id = collection_users.find(
    {"first_name": {"$in: ['Alex', 'Andrew']"}},
    {"id": 1, "_id": 0}
)

for i in select_users_id:
    print i.values()
```

I receive error message:

```
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: set(["$in: ['Alex', 'Andrew']"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check your query. You missed the closing quotes for `$in` operator.

```
select_users_id = collection_users.find(
    {"first_name": {"$in": ['Alex', 'Andrew']}},
    {"id": 1, "_id": 0}
)
```